# In a maven project, is there a way to find the dependencies whose version is not specified explicitly

Tags: maven

My java maven project contains a bunch of sub-projects, something like below

```
|- parent
     |- core
          |- db
          |- xml 
     |- util
     |- config
```

In all projects' `pom.xml` files, there are a several dependencies defined. However, only for a few of them, `<version/>` is specified. For example

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
      <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
      <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    </dependency>  
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

As you can see, for `org.apache.ant`, the `version` is explicitly mentioned as `1.9.7`. However, for `org.apache.xmlbeans`, a version is automatically inferred based on several factors. While it's a convenient feature, it also makes the version sometimes unpredictable when the third party library project is very active and could have other dependencies.

So, the question is, I want to find all the dependencies that do *not* have the `version` specified explicitly.

I tried `help:effective-pom`. It lists all dependencies across all sub-projects but it also outputs the version that is inferred.

You can say, I am looking at a variant of `effective-pom` which recursively lists all dependencies for all sub-projects but does not fetch any version automatically unless otherwise specified explicitly. Once I have such list (in xml format), I can apply some xqueries on the xml output to filter out what I want and make the necessary changes.

EDIT:
I am looking for dependencies which do not have the `<version>` tag. It's still *okay (?)* for me if a range is specified using [Ranges](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/resolve-ranges.html)

Comment: dependencyManagement is not for declaring dependency, so you may have a dependencyManagement's dependency with version but actual dependency without version, or vice versa.  Both will work fine as version is actually declared.  Not sure what your question really means

Comment: If you define a dependency in dependencyManagement without a version and don't get a warning the dependency is already defined anywhere else (probably in a parent)..otherwise you will get warnings about the dependencies without versions...

Comment: Agreed @AdrianShum. And that's what your comment got me thinking. Looks like my unstable build is not due to unpredictable versions of dependencies. It's most probably due to [automatic resolution of plugins](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-AutomaticPluginVersionResolution). Thanks!

Comment: @RakeshN For unspecified plugin version, it should be easily identifiable by building.  Maven 3+ is giving warning of plugin without version iirc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to handle this directly from Maven, but you can try using XPath on the entire POM file.  Try using this expression:

```
//dependency[not(version)]
```

This will return all `<dependency>` nodes which do *not* contain a child node `<version>`.

Comment: I have tried that, but I have like 100 pom.xml in multiple hierarchical folders. It's not practical for me to run that xpath/xquery on _each_ of the `pom.xml`

Comment: @RakeshN Well you could write a Java code which scans each POM file with this XPath expression...but then again that also sounds a bit draconian.  I will leave this answer up as the best possibility unless someone else offers a pure Maven solution.

Comment: @RakeshN It is a reasonable solution.  Depending on your platform you can script this.  For Linux, a combination of find and xmlstarlet would make this really easy.

Comment: If saxon xquery processor can be used, then  --> let $col := collection("file:///your/project/directory?select=pom.xml;recurse=yes") can be used; which I did with some success. However, after some more analysis triggered by @Adrian comment, I think I am on the wrong path :(